# Batch - Extract string before the specified character

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch

How to get the string before the character hyphen? The following code gets the string after the hyphen. How can I reverse this?

```
set string=1.0.10-SNAPSHOT

echo %string:*-=%

SNAPSHOT
```

But I want the 1.0.10 instead of SNAPSHOT of if the string is RELEASE

Comment: You want extract 1.0.10?

Comment: yes that's right

Answer (score 1):

for extract string before hyphen (special charcter) you need used for

```
@echo off
set string=1.0.10-SNAPSHOT
echo %string%
for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %%a in ("%string%") do (
  echo %%a
  )
```